# Fit image on selection grid in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I want to scale and fit image to selection grid vertically and horizontally. I used an array texture2D to display images on selection grid.

[image]

This will be the result.
[image]

Code is here :

```
public Texture2D[] arr_texture2d_image;
private int sel_menu_int = 0;

 void Start(){
            arr_texture2d_image = new Texture2D[sel_menu_strs.Length];
            for(int i = 0; i < sel_menu_strs.Length; i++){
                WWW www = new WWW ("http://192.168.149.60/hmsx/api/" + sel_menu_strs[i]);
                StartCoroutine (WaitForRequest(www,i));
            }

IEnumerator WaitForRequest(WWW www,int i)
    {
        yield return www;
            if (www.isDone == true) {
                arr_texture2d_image[i] = www.texture as Texture2D;
                www.Dispose();
            } 
    }

}

void OnGUI(){
    sel_menu_int = GUILayout.SelectionGrid (sel_menu_int, arr_texture2d_image, no_of_thumbs_x ,gui_skn.button);
}
```

I used this but nothing works.

```
Texture2D texTmp = new Texture2D(280, 160, TextureFormat.DXT1, false);
                www.LoadImageIntoTexture(texTmp);
                arr_texture2d_image[i] = texTmp;
```

Comment: i suggest you to use unity's new GUI (UUI) if you are using version 4.6 or above. you will not require any coding in that case. I can help you in that if you are willing to use UUI.

Comment: Okay thanks for your suggestion but it was a project and we are near to finished.

Comment: Cant see you images, any chance to you upload in a different host? Where is your grid code? It would be nice to take a look too or you already couldn't code any idea?